# Synchronized Audio Streaming over Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, audio-streaming

I am working on an iPhone app that needs to stream audio file to multiple devices (iPhone) connected via Bluetooth and play it in the Synchronized way, that is, all the devices starts playing the audio file simultaneously. 
I am able to make a connection and stream the audio packet and even play the audio file, but the only issue that I am facing is the Latency. All the devices starts playing the audio file at different time, I want all of them to play the same audio packet together. Is there any way I can make them play audio file synchronously?

Answer (score -1):

I remember glancing over audio broadcast option in the bluetooth spec. Not sure whether iphone supports it..